# Rust WASM memory.buffer TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'buffer')

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen, rust-wasm

I'm learning wasm knowledge recently, and I want to use memory.buffer-related knowledge, but I can't run the content of this chapter smoothly:

https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-bindgen/reference/types/pointers.html

Can anyone kindly help me get it up and running? ,  thank you very much.

I'm actually newbie in rust、 nodejs and ts, so I'm confused by import and require.

I don't know how to configure and run it.

Some environments and used methods:

```
rustup 1.25.2
rustc 1.68.2
cargo 1.68.2
wasm-pack 0.11.1

wasm-bindgen = "0.2.86"
wasm-bindgen-futures = "0.4.36"


node v16.19.1
npm 8.19.3


// both tried build and --target nodejs
wasm-pack build
wasm-pack build --target nodejs

npm install


node index.js // run js directly
npm run build && node index.js // build then run
```

I still have no idea.